# python Argparse: how to enter default values when using repeated options/arguments and yet some may be dropped in the command line

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to write a code that connects (via ssh) to multiple machines (servers), using a given ip address, username and password given by the user for each machine, and gets a list of files for each machine, in order to do something with them. The goal is for the user to be able to enter all those options and arguments via a command-line interface. I am using python's argparse module.

In the easier scenario the user calls the function via the following list of options and arguments: (assuming the code is save in myFile.py)

```
$ python3 mFile.py --machine ip1 --username u1 --pass p1 --file f11 f12 f13 --machine ip2 --username u2 --pass p2 --file f21 f22
```

The following python code could handle the above usage:

```
parser.add_argument('-m', '--machine',  action='append', const=["m1"], nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--pass', action='append', const =['default_pass'], nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', action='append', const =['default_uname'], nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', nargs='+', action='append')
```

and if I run `print(parser.parse_args())` I will get:

```
Namespace(file=[['f11', 'f12', 'f13'], ['f21', 'f22']], machine=['ip1', 'ip2'], password=['p1', 'p2'], user=['u1', 'u2'])
```

which is all nice and dandy. But here is the problem that I am having: 
The user may drop some of the options and arguments, in which case a default value should be used. The user may drop username AND/OR password for a particular machine (since some of the servers have the same username and/or password) or drop the machine ip, and so I want the following possible calls at the command line and yet get pretty much the same namespace as I had above (except w/ default values in place of missing options/args):

For instance user drops username and password for the 2nd machine:

```
$ python3 mFile.py --machine ip1 --username u1 --pass p1 --file f11 f12 f13 --machine ip2 --file f21 f22
```

and yet I get the following namespace for the above usage:

```
Namespace(file=[['f11', 'f12', 'f13'], ['f21', 'f22']], machine=['ip1', 'ip2'], password=['p1', 'default_pass'], user=['u1','default_uname'])
```

Or the user drops the machine ip which by default would mean the current machine he's sitting at:

```
$ python3 mFile.py --file f11 f12 f13 --machine p2 --username u2 --pass p2 --files f21 f22
```

and I still get the following namespace:

```
Namespace(file=[['f11', 'f12', 'f13'], ['f21', 'f22']], machine=['current_ip', 'ip2'], password=['default_pass', 'p2'], user=['default_uname', 'u2'])
```

Note that if the username or password is dropped, some default username and password string can be used, but if the machine ip is dropped, the ip of the current machine should be retrieved and used. Also I'm assuming the user never drops the list of files, since that's necessary.

I tried using the "default" option when using `add_argument` but that just appends the default values to the lists mindlessly at the beginning of the list and not where the missing option/arg occurred. Essentially all the lists (i.e. file, machine, pass and username) should have same length at the end.

I have no clue how to make this work! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With the `?` and `const`, your users can provide a 'dummy' entry:

```
In [122]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [123]: parser.add_argument('-m', '--machine',  action='append', const=["m1"], nargs='?')
In [124]: parser.parse_args(''.split())
Out[124]: Namespace(machine=None)
In [125]: parser.parse_args('-m one -m -m three'.split())
Out[125]: Namespace(machine=['one', ['m1'], 'three'])
```

The `machine` action is invoked each time a `-m` flag is found, filling in the provided value or the `const` is none.  But the `default` is entered only once - at the beginning of parsing.

Since each optional is processed independently there isn't a way of telling the parser to expect 3 of each, or to expect them in any particular order, or to fill in missing one.  Obviously after parsing you can check the lengths of the attribute lists, but there's no way of know which one is missing.

I can't think of any simple way (or for that matter complex) adding such expectations to an `argparse` parser.